# Date inconsistency across browsers - MVC 5 date from model

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

I have this in a view model:

```
[Required]
[Display(Name = "Date of birth")]
[DataType(DataType.Date), DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }
```

And on the form:

```
<div class="form-group">
      @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DateOfBirth, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
      <div class="col-md-10">
             @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DateOfBirth, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
             @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DateOfBirth, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
      </div>
</div>
```

Works nicely in all browsers apart from Chrome which only displays "dd/MM/yyyy" instead of populating the field with the value from the model.

So I tried changing the date format in the ViewModel:

```
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
```

Chrome starts showing the model value in the format dd/MM/yyyy (potentially due to my local region settings?), but all the other browsers start showing the yyyy-MM-dd format.

I get that it's an international recognised standard, but being an Australian website the design we were working with was in the format of dd/MM/yyyy.

Can I get it working so that all the browsers show dd/MM/yyyy without needing to resort to:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.DateOfBirth, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" }, @Value = Model.DateOfBirth.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") })
```

Which means that Chrome doesn't provide the date picker functionality.

Using latest version of MVC, with a c# view model.  Looks like Opera behaves similarly to Chrome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We've ended up just using separate drop down lists for the day, month, year fields.  I imagine the other option would have been to find a datepicker plugin that worked in all browsers (and on mobile devices).  Annoying!

Answer (score 1):

It appears Chrome only accepts the format as `yyyy-MM-dd`, so the following will work

```
[Required]
[Display(Name = "Date of birth")]
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }
```

It will then display the assigned date (using your regional settings) rather than the date string.  I guess that has an advantage in that a user in another culture would see the date in their culture rather than yours.

This actually in accordance with the [specifications](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#date-state-(type=date))

This does not help much if you are also using `@Html.DisplayFor(m=> m.DateOfBirth)`. One workaround would be to create a DisplayTemplate `DateTime.cshtml` that formats the date string using `.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")`

Comment: Someone on the team wasn't 100% convinced about defining a EditorTemplate for the date type in case we want to do something funky with it on another screen.  Or do you control it in the view you want to use it in ?

Comment: Sorry, not sure I understand - do you mean EditorTemplate or DisplayTemplate? - from your question you do not appear to be using an editor template for `DateTime`

Comment: I might be getting confused about terminology.  It needs to be an editable field in the correct format with the date prepopulated.

Comment: If in the `DisplayFormatAttribute`, you use `DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}"` and then in the view use `@Html.EditorFor(m=> m.DateOfBirth)` then this will render `<input type="date" ...` which will use the browsers internal datepicker (including being properly displayed in Chrome).  Because you need to use this format it means that if you used @Html.DisplayFor() in a non edit page, the date would be displayed as "2014-08-09" which may not be what you want, hence my suggestion to use a custom `DisplayTemplate`

Comment: Ahh ok - not concerned about a non edit page.  But I am concerned about Chrome and Opera showing date as expected (dd/MM/yyyy) due to the way they handle the date input correctly, but all the other browsers just showing it (in an editable state) in the format yyyy-MM-dd.  Sorry if that wasn't clear

Comment: OK, now understand.  Chrome and Opera have actually implemented this in accordance with the standards (i.e. the date input string should be "yyyy-MM-dd" and then displayed in accordance with the browsers regional settings. IE (typically) has not so you are probably out of luck. Not sure what you can do other than use a DatePicker plugin