# Confusion with Date Format asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a confusion with Date Format, in create mode, the validator accept only the format `dd-MM-yyyy` instead of `dd.MM.yyyy`. And in edit mode it proposes to me the format `dd.MM.yyyy` that is not valid so I have to change it each time.

Here is the date property:

```
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd.MM.yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
public DateTime dateOut
{
        get;
        set;
}
```

Could someone help me to find where is the error ?

Thank you.

Comment: Are you using `@Html.EditorFor()` to render the browsers datepicker?

Comment: Yes I am using @Html.EditorFor()

Comment: No, in Internet Explorer

Comment: As a test, change the format to `yyyy-MM-dd`. This should display the date correctly and in the format of your culture (e.g. dd-MM-yyyy if thats your culture)

Comment: It doesn't work anymore, it seems that in  create mode it confuses '.' by '-'. I don't know why ?

Comment: Did you try `yyyy-MM-dd`? (hyphens not dots) - it worked for me

Comment: yes I have try it it. Now in create mode dd-MM-yyyy is valid, it ok but in edit mode, it displays me yyyy-MM-dd that is not valid I have to change it to dd-MM-yyyy

Comment: What is the difference between `Create` and 'Edit' mode? Do you mean Display mode?

Comment: Create mode is when you fill the form to add a instance of your model, and edit mode is when you want to modify properties of an instance, so it displays you in the form values that you have filled before, and here appears the error when submitting the modified instance

Comment: Certainly does not work that way in web-kit browsers. You might want to have a look at [this question and my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25302782/date-inconsistency-across-browsers-mvc-5-date-from-model/25336813#25336813)

Comment: Yes but it is exactly the same that we have tried so far

Comment: Nobody have any ideas ?

Comment: No solution for my problem ?

Answer (score 2):

The periods in the format specifies the date separator in the current culture. You can use literal periods instead:

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd'.'MM'.'yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `EditorFor()` instead of `TextBoxFor()` as :-

View :-

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.dateOut)
```

Model :-

```
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd.MM.yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
public DateTime dateOut
{
    get;
    set;
}
```

Comment: I am using  EditorFor not TextBoxFor

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Date, "{0:dd.MM.yyyy}")
```

Comment: The same not working, same confusion '-' works but '.' not and same also in edit mode propose dd.MM.yyyy but not valid when submitting

Answer (score 0):

I found it, works for me. It's allows form to be send if date is in format that you have specified:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Date, "{0:dd.MM.yyyy}")

<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(function ($) {
        $.validator.addMethod('date',
        function (value, element) {
            if (this.optional(element)) {
                return true;
            }

            var ok = true;
            try {
                $.datepicker.parseDate('dd.mm.yy', value);
            }
            catch (err) {
                ok = false;
            }
            return ok;
        });
    });
$("form").each(function () { $.data($(this)[0], 'validator', false); });
    $.validator.unobtrusive.parse("form");
</script>
```

Comment: I have tried it but the script does not work, maybe I have not implement it well ?

Comment: So there is no solution for my problem ?

Comment: maybe try to install https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.jQuery.Unobtrusive.Ajax/ and https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.jQuery.Unobtrusive.Validation/